# Selects dependentes com JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como popular um segundo select de acordo com primeiro a partir de um arquivo JSON.

HTML:

`<select id="município_id" name="municipio">`

`<select id="estabelecimento_id" name="estabelecimento">`

JSON:
`[{"municipio":"pesqueira","estabelecimento":"UBS pesqueira","cod":"7866"},{"municipio":"pesqueira","estabelecimento":"UBS centro","cod":"7767"},{"municipio":"custodia","estabelecimento":"Pronto Atendimento em saúde","cod":"8655"}]...`

O JSON é grande! Tem essa estrutura, cidades podem se repetir mas estabelecimento não. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: Você precisa transforma em objeto esse json. E depois adiciona option no select e depois criar evento quando um select for mudando

Comment: Se refere a um COMBO BOX ?
Você seleciona a cidade, e carrega os estabelecimentos em outro <select>?

Comment: Pergunta mal formulada

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Chegai leo. rs rs

Comment: Sim Risk, seleciona a cidade e carrega os estabelecimentos, ambos pelo nome!

Comment: Mais algum carregamento ou só esse @sedarky

Comment: Só esse mesmo @Risk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde amigo, você tem um problema com esse JSON, ele não tem a melhor estrutura pra que você trabalhe, o ideal é que o municipio fosse único algo como:

```
[
  {
    "municipio":"pesqueira",
    "estabelecimentos": {
      {"name": "UBS pesqueira","cod":"7866"},
      {"name": "UBS pesqueira","cod":"7866"}
    }
  }
]
```

Mas se você não puder mexer nessa estrutura do JSON você pode filtrar os municipios desse JSON pra depois montar os valores de estabelecimento

```
const municipios = [...new Set(objeto.map(obj => obj.municipio)]

const selectMunicipios = document.querySelector('#município_id')

selectMunicipios.onchange = () => {
  const municipio = selectMunicipios.value

  const filtrado = objeto.filter(item => item.municipio === municipio)
  const estabelecimentos = filtrado.map(item => item.estabelecimento)
  const selectEstabelecimento = document.querySelector('#estabelecimento_id')
  
  selectEstabelecimento.innerHtml = ''

  estabelecimentos.forEach(estabelecimento => {
    const option = document.createElement('option')
    option.innerText = estabelecimento

    selectEstabelecimento.appendChild(option)
  })

}

municipios.forEach(municipio => {

  const option = document.createElement('option')
  selectMunicipios.appendChild(option)
  
})
```

Esse código deve funcionar se eu não escrevi nada errado ;), onde eu colocquei o nome **objeto** significa que você deve chamar o seu objeto JSON.

Lembrando esse código só é necessário caso você realmente não possa corrigir a estrutura do seu JSON, se você corrigir esse JSON seria bem melhor e mais fácil o trabalho.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: São 3984 linhas! Demoraria muito!

Comment: não intendi, o que exatamente demoraria muito?

Comment: Editar na mão o arquivo JSON, deixar ele estruturado: cada município com seus estabelecimentos!

Comment: como chamaria o objeto JSON?

Comment: Na linha: ```const municipios = [...new Set(obj_.cnes.map(obj => obj.municipio))]``` dá erro ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```

Comment: você precisa chamar com o nome da variável que está recebendo o JSON que você disse aí no post, lembrando que se você estiver recebendo um JSON puro então você deve converter ele em objeto javascript com o código:
```
const objeto = JSON.parse(nome_do_objeto_em_string)
```

Comment: Estou fazendo assim: ```var = [{"municipio":"nome_municipio","cod":"1234"},{}...]```. Depois: ```var obj_ = JSON.stringify(var);``` Então ```const municipios = [...new Set(obj_.map(obj => obj.municipio))]```. Tentei JSON.parse() mas dava erro, daí pesquisando...mudei para stringify, mas continua!

Comment: O stringify não ajuda nesse caso é como se você estivesse convertendo string em string. Você pode tentar fazer assim: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(texto)). Se continuar dando erro é importante você testar esse JSON em um validador JSON online mesmo, pois existe grande chance de estar quebrado.

Comment: Olhando novamente para o seu exemplo você está criando uma variável como 1 array de uma posição string. Tente colocar tudo como string assim: var = JSON.parse('[{"municipio":"nome_municipio","cod":"1234"},{}...]')

Comment: obrigado pela presteza! Infelizmente não deu certo. Fiz como você falou ```obj_ = JSON.parse('[{"..."}]')``` mas ficou dando erro: ```Invalid or unexpected token```.

Comment: Fiz uma solução com session(django): pegando valor de cidade numa view e recuperando em outra, consultando os estabelecimentos no bd e renderizando para outra view!